# How to clear Navigation Drawer (All Fragments) when sign out

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I want to remove/clear Navigation fragments after sign out button press.

**Details**

In Fragment I have a button where I want to sign out and go back to login screen (Activity), **I have tried all the possible solutions from here but didn't get the solution for my problem**. The problem is same, from login activity when I press back button it goes to signout fragment again, where I already use the code below

I'm using app.Fragment and below I'm using following ans,

**1st Solution**

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

**2nd Solution**

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
int count = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) { fm.popBackStack(); }
```

**3rd Soultion**

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack(getFragmentManager()
               .getBackStackEntryAt(0).getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

**4th Solution**

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
manager.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

startActivity(new Intent(mContext, Login_Activity.class));
```

None of the above code is working for me, need suggestions and solutions thanks

Comment: You need to clear the Activity stack when you start the login activity. Not sure why a login activity would have a FragmentManager

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
```

from your fragment
Or call

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
```

from your activity

Call this from your fragment, which you want to remove on signout

Comment: One more thing, you provide an identifier while adding and popping backstack.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin solution. It should be feasible in java too.
This will remove all the background activities, hence there is no need for loops.  You can put this code in your signout/logout method

```
val intent = Intent(this, ypurAfterSignOutAcitivy::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, finishing the activity and self-relaunch it with an extra worked fine
(I am using a single activity, for several you could broadcast your activities and finish them)

```js
fun logout() {//this is on MainActivity
  val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
    putExtra(EXTRA_START_FRAG, R.id.loginFragment)
  }
  startActivity(intent)
  finish()
}
```

then on restart I check for this extra and navigate to it

```js
navController.navigate(extras.getInt(EXTRA_START_FRAG))
```

my guess is that you can do similar even thou I'm using navigation components

Answer (score -1):

At time of sign out use `getActivity.finish()` and also end another activities..